# Coldfusion SQL Server giving The hexadecimal string is invalid

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am getting this error -

```
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]The hexadecimal string is invalid
```

when I run the following query -

```
<cfquery datasource="#getDatasource()#" name="qryAdminActivity">
    select * from v2_admin_activity
      where adminId = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#arguments.adminId#"> 
</cfquery>
```

The Row in question in the database is looks like this

[image]

Anyone has any idea what is wrong here?

::::EDIT::::

I found that the problem is with this string in the database -

```
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt; &lt;activities&gt;&lt;activity&gt;&lt;date&gt;{ts &apos;2013-02-19 16:36:43&apos;}&lt;/date&gt;&lt;query&gt;Test,,,1,2013-02-19 16:36:43.625,1&lt;/query&gt;&lt;className&gt;moduleDAO&lt;/className&gt;&lt;functionName&gt;addNewSubModule&lt;/functionName&gt;&lt;type&gt;Add&lt;/type&gt;&lt;/activity&gt;&lt;/activities&gt;
```

Now could anyobe tell me what is wrong with this?

The column type in database is varchar(max)

Comment: What's the value of = arguments.adminId?

Comment: its a numeric value. in this case it is 8

Comment: If you run the query in management studio does it run successfully?

Comment: How did isolate that string as being the culprit? I ask because whatever might be wrong with that wouldn't - to me - be likely to yield that error message you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this error occurring on the query or on the display of the results? How are you displaying the output from that query? Is it trying to parse the XML in your result? Is that XML valid? I've found that storing XML in SQL Server as anything other than the XML datatype can sometimes cause issues when trying to treat it as XML again. I guess it would depend on how you're ultimately using that XML string.

I would recommend working through each of your dynamic CF variables and replacing them with a valid hard-coded value until you can narrow it down to the one causing the problem. And try replacing that xml in the database with another value. It looks like it might be trying to parse that varchar(max) as XML.

Answer (score 1):

Just faced the same issue. It's a CF query caching for me (no cachedwithin used though).

### Reason

In my case, it was due to a change in the SQL Table Field type. I set the field to varbinary by mistake, and kept working on the CFC (SQL query) and the methods calling till I hit that error - even after changing the field type to varchar.

### Resolution

Just type anything in the cfquery I added the silly 1=1 to the where statement, refreshed my classes and Voila!
I'm gonna remove that extra text form my query now.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that after removing the cfqueryparam tag from the query, it started working -

```
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#arguments.adminId#">
```

to

```
adminId = #arguments.adminId#
```

Weird but worked.

Thanks to all for the answers.

Comment: Be careful with this. Make sure you haven't opened yourself up for SQL injection. That's one of the primary benefits of cfqueryparam. Try adding it back in and using CF_SQL_INTEGER as the cfsqltype. What is the SQL datatype of adminID? Make sure that your adminID, cfsqltype and arguments.adminID are all compatible datatypes.

Comment: Well Spotted Shawn. I did it as a quick fix for the client, but now I will go back and do it with cf_sql_integer.